# How do I do simple user input in python?

Tags: python, input, user-input

I'm just playing with input and variables. I'm trying to run a simple function:

```
slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

I'd like to prompt the user to enter `y2`, `y1`, `x2` and `x1`. What is the simplest, cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function to prompt the user for input, and [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) to convert the user input from a string to a float:

```
x1 = float(input("x1: "))
y1 = float(input("y1: "))
x2 = float(input("x2: "))
y2 = float(input("y2: "))
```

If you're using python 2, use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead.

Comment: I did that and I get this error: y2 = int(raw_input("y2: "))
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: Are you on Python 3? If so, use `input()`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest way:

```
 x1 = float(raw_input("Enter x1: "))
```

Note that the `raw_input()` function returns a *string*, which is converted to a floating point number with `float()`. If you type something other than a number, you will get an exception:

```
>>> float(raw_input())
a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): a
```

If you're using Python 3 (it sounds like you are), use `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
foo=input('Please enter a value:')
```

Where the string 'Please enter a value:' would be your message, and foo would be your variables.

Comment: ...and if you enter `import os, sys; os.unlink(sys.argv[0])` instead of a number after the prompt, your script will delete itself (at least in Python 2.x).

Comment: My answer is in relation to Python 3.

Comment: And my comment incorrect anyway.  I just wanted to make the point that this is inherently insecure in Python 2.x.  For Python 3.x, you should convert the result to a float. (The correct version of the above would have been `__import__("os").unlink(__import__("sys").argv[0])`, since only an expression gets evaluated.)

Answer (score 0):

If the user is entering the inputs in just one line with space as delimiting word between those inputs, you can write:

```
val1, val2, val3 = raw_input().split(' ')
```

Now, you can change it to:

```
val = float(val1)
```

The awesome trick is that in this way you don't waste your space creating a new list and storing your values in that and then fetching it.